# read encrypted LUKS hard drive from another machine

Tags: luks

If I LUKS encrypted a hard drive using linux machine A, can I read the data on it using machine B? Of course assuming I know the passphrase of the disk. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming the passphrase you know is a LUKS passphrase in the first place.

LUKS is designed so that the actual master keys that encrypt the blocks are part of the LUKS header and any user key like a passphrase used to unlock the disk simply decrypts a copy of the master keys.

However, if the passphrase is used to get the real user key from some other source, like unsealing it from a TPM object in some outside system that interfaces with LUKS then maybe not.  Often a system like that cannot be moved between devices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all the metadata needed to access the data are present on the disk (unless you use detached LUKS header, but that's not a standard use case) and the encryption is not tied to the hardware of machine where it was created (TPM support is now coming to LUKS but it's a relatively new feature and even if you have it configured, you should have a backup passphrase that works without the TPM chip). All you need is the passphrase and `cryptsetup luksOpen`.